# Arm size growth and halt

Tags: supplements, muscle-mass, bellyfat

Meanwhile I was working 2 months ago, I saw change in my bicep part of arm change, the girth change and it seems bigger, I was taking supplements,but I was told by many it's too many. While I saw changes and I was amazed. Should I be taking it. My aim is build muscle and loose fat.
The supp was provided me from a trainer I hired.

[image: list of supp I took during one month]

Comment: That's a lot of supplements. How much are you paying this guy to give you pills? Have you considered seeing how you do while just eating food?

Comment: @Dave Liepmann I hired him for few weeks and than discounted afterwards, typically I m lazy, freelance computer job so sitting all day expect for gym, which is too lazy too as I don't have energy or feel tired to do anything.

Comment: Supplements didn't cause your arms to grow.  That was work you put in.  Supplements simply supply what your diet lacks.  Also understand that after the initial quick increases, further increase requires even more work.

Comment: @Berin Loritsch what do you mean by "further increase requires even more work"

Comment: Lifting for hypertrophy requires a lot of work.  The simple rules of getting stronger/bigger require that you stimulate your muscles in a way they are not used to in order for them to adapt.  That can be as easy as adding weight, or as complex as cycling though different movement patterns for the same muscle.  Both are used in bodybuilding, as well as changes in tempo, etc.  You have to make your training more difficult to force adaptation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trainer gave you these supplements, that gives you reason to be skeptical (even suspicious) about his knowledge of the body, its mechanisms, and diet & nutrition.

Let's go over a couple of his recommendations:

- Vitamin C 3000mg per day - **Recommended daily intake of vitamin C is about 90mg for an adult male** but many athletes can require upwards of 100mg per day. (Ultra endurance athletes may require as much as 500mg per day- marathon runners and the like). Since vitamin C is water soluble, any more than what your body uses is urinated out. AND since many juices and foods in our diets contain vitamin C, you may be getting more like 3500 mg per day. Essentially all your trainer is doing is giving you expensive urine, and REALLY stressing your kidneys, since the kidneys have to filter all this out. **High doses of vitamin C supplementation have been linked to kidney stones, and Mayo Clinic recommends not exceeding 2000mg as an upper limit.** (http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/high-dose-vitamin-c-linked-to-kidney-stones-in-men-201302055854, http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/vitamin-c/dosing/hrb-20060322)
- Cinnamon Extract- Supplementation of **cinnamon extract has been shown to help blood glucose levels in DIABETICS**, however, (much like above) the dose your trainer is giving you is absurd. In *"Cinnamon extract improves fasting blood glucose and glycosylated hemoglobin level in Chinese patients with type 2 diabetes., by Lu T1, Sheng H, Wu J, Cheng Y, Zhu J, Chen Y."* **subjects were given 360mg per day as a maximum dose**. Let's assume cinnamon extract DOES help non-diabetics as well. If so, a small dose might not be a bad thing. However, 2000mg per day is bad news- most cinnamon extracts have coumarin (which gives it the strong flavor), and coumarin has been shown to have negative effects on both kidney and liver function.
- Glutamine, BCAA's, Arginine, and individual Amino Acids - Your body creates muscle by taking protein (amino acids) and using it to help satellite cells fuse to muscle fibers. Since you need all amino acids to make muscle, **taking one or two amino acids, or just BCAA's will do little to nothing to build muscle- but again, and this is why I have been critical of your trainer, all this extra protein and amino acid will have to be filtered by the kidneys. bad bad bad.**
- Multivitamin - Same reasons as above (kidney stress, unnecessary levels/doses, you probably get most of it from your diet anyway...)

Bottom Line:
Unfortunately, there are no real requirements to be a trainer (most can simply pay $100, take a test and then dispense whatever bad information they want to people who will listen). It is an unfortunate part of the business but it is a reality, like trying to be a race car instructor after taking your 16 year old driver's test.

**Ultimately, if you are eating a good diet of about 60% carbohydrates, 20% protein, 20% fat (and avoiding trans-fats, saturated fats, etc) your diet will cover all of your nutritional needs.** 
If you are sitting all day except for the gym, try adding some more exercise to your day (walking before or to work, climbing stairs instead of elevators, etc).

Comment: So how much should i be taking? How much mg of each

Comment: I would actually stay away from most of those supplements, maybe a multivitamin to make up for some _small_ holes in your diet (some may disagree with me about my stance on supplements, though). But if you're sitting most of the day like you said, and you workout (a strength training workout does not burn as many calories as you might think), just eat a good diet of complex carbs (brown rice, whole grains), protein (chicken, fish, beans) and "good" mono-unsaturated fats (olive oil, fish, peanut butter). Try: http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/fitness/in-depth/exercise/art-20045506

Answer (score 0):

The photo you put up looks like a fine thing to do, but taking 'magic pills' your trainer gave to you sounds pretty risky to me.

Give some thought to what Dave commented though, JUST EAT. That list looks like it could get pretty expensive.

Go check these out:

http://articles.elitefts.com/training-articles/integrative-bodybuilding-peri-workout-recovery-supplementation-part-1/

http://articles.elitefts.com/training-articles/integrative-bodybuilding-peri-workout-recovery-supplementation-part-2/

http://articles.elitefts.com/nutrition/integrative-bodybuilding-peri-workout-recovery-supplementation-part-3/

Comment: what make you say that

Comment: Which part haha?

Comment: "Risky to me" Line, why is it risky

Comment: Those pills could be dianabol, YOU wouldn't know.

Comment: Let me ask, do you know what he gave to you? Or did he just say - "hey take these"?

Comment: No, but I did some research and BCAA protein shake, zinc, vitamin c, sound good. l-Car, Beta-arg too?

Comment: Please read the links I just added to my answer. If you really are interested in this stuff, you'll find it very interesting.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why my bicep girth got wide in one month of taking it and not now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15425/discussion-between-tannman357-and-nofel).

Comment: Can you summarize the articles, rather than just linking and saying "go read"? If the links ever die, the answer is useless.

Comment: I _could_ do that....